# Как мне преобразовать обычную строку в JSON формат

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Я имею обычный документ TXT который загружаю на сайт через input, дальше читаю его с помощью FileReader и получаю просто текст

[image]

каждую строку нужно привести в формат JSON, где ключ до знака "=" значение после, если знака"=" нет то и значение отсутсвует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз текст в вопросе текстом не привёл, то проверяй и отлаживай сам.
Но вообще, что-то такое:

```
var res = Object.create(null)

text.replace(/^([^=]*)(=)(.*)$/gm, (m, k, e, v) => {
  res[k] = e ? v : null
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
```

Comment: Ты лучший, спасибо за быстрый ответ!

Comment: @РобертДауни, если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него. Если в коде есть ошибки, напиши в комментарии, поправлю.

Comment: Все работает как надо, еще раз спасибо)